iOS App Install Tracking Issue in Meta Ads Campaign
Xcode version
14.3.1
Facebook iOS SDK version
17.4.0
Dependency Manager
CocoaPods
SDK Framework
Core
Goals
We aim to accurately track iOS app installs generated through our Meta Ads campaigns to ensure that our ad spend aligns with the reported campaign results.
Expected results
When running an iOS app campaign, we expect the "App Installs" metric in the campaign dashboard to display the actual number of app installs attributed to the ads, consistent with the app install events received by the Facebook SDK.
Actual results
Despite the SDK and App Ads Helper confirming that app install events are being tracked:
The "App Installs" metric in Campaign ID: xxx remains empty.
However, in the Events Manager (link), 142 iOS app install events were logged between November 30th, 00:00, and December 3rd, 11:36.
This discrepancy prevents us from confidently scaling our campaigns as planned.
Steps to reproduce
Setup: Integrated the react-native-fbsdk-next with Expo for our app (App ID: xxx).
Campaign Launch: Initiated an iOS app install campaign (Campaign ID: xxxx).
Data Check: Used the following tools:
App Ads Helper: Confirmed iOS app install events are tracked (see attached screenshot).
Events Manager: Verified that 142 iOS app install events were logged during the specified period (see attached screenshot).
Campaign Results: Checked the campaign dashboard, where the "App Installs" metric was empty, even though installs were recorded in other tools.
Code samples & details
SDK: react-native-fbsdk-next
iOS SDK Version: FBiOSSDK.17.4.0 (managed via react-native-fbsdk-next)
App ID: xxxx
Campaign ID: xxxx
Integration Snippet:
expo react native
import { Settings } from "react-native-fbsdk-next";

useEffect(() => {
  const initializeFacebookSDK = async () => {
    // Initialize the Facebook SDK
    Settings.initializeSDK();

    // Optional: Enable tracking if granted by the user
    const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === "granted") {
      await Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true);
    }
  };

  initializeFacebookSDK();
}, []);


Request for Support
Validation: Could you confirm if our SDK integration is correct and fully functional?
Resolution: If the SDK is working (as the App Ads Helper suggests), could you investigate why app installs are not reflected in the campaign's "App Installs" metric?
